# Iterating through a vector of maps

Tags: c++, vector, hashmap, iteration

I'm new to learning c++ and I am having trouble trying to iterate through my code.

```
vector<map<string, char>> skills;
map<string, char> frontFloat;
map<string, char> frontGlide;

skills.push_back(frontFloat);
skills.push_back(frontGlide);

frontFloat["Wetface"]='C';
frontFloat["relaxed"]='C';
frontFloat["comfortable"]='I';

// ...

for (auto x : skills) {
   for (auto it=x.begin(); it!=x.end(); ++it){
      cout<< it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';
   }
}
```

I'm trying to iterate through a `vector` and further iterate through each `map` within the vector.

My `for` loop doesn't seem to print anything and I have pushed values into the map. Please advise.

Comment: can you show how you insert the values?

Comment: Your example doesn't push anything into the map. It's likely that's where the problem is, and that's what you should be showing. Btw, `auto x : skills` copies each and every map, you don't wanna be doing that when there's a lot of data to be copied.

Comment: Since you used the `hashmap` tag, I'd like to point out that `std::map` is **not** a hashmap! It is a self-balancing binary search tree (i.e. a Red-Black Tree). For a hashmap, use `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: "and I have pushed values into the map" - not in your posted code you haven't. Please post exanple code as [mcve] whenever possible.

Comment: Irrelevant to your question, but you most likely want `auto& x` or `const auto& x`.

Comment: Why are you using iterators and not a range-for loop for the inner loop?

Comment: `vector<map<string, char>> skills;`
        `map<string, char> frontFloat;`
        `map<string, char> frontGlide;`

        `skills.push_back(frontFloat);`
       `skills.push_back(frontGlide);`

        `frontFloat["Wetface"]='C';`
        `frontFloat["relaxed"]='C';`
        `frontFloat["comfortable"]='I';`

Answer (score 1):

```
skills.push_back(frontFloat);
// ...
frontFloat["Wetface"]='C';
```

The `map` on which you set `WetFace` is **not the same one** that is inside the `vector`. You make a **copy** of `frontFloat` inside the `vector`.

So when you do your interation over the `map` **inside** the `vector`, it is not the same `map` that you set elements in.

To add to the map that is inside the `vector`, do something like

```
skills.back()["WetFace"] = 'C';
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to BoBTFish's answer, use indexes of vector elements to manipulate with them.

```
vector<map<string, char>> skills;
map<string, char> frontFloat;
map<string, char> frontGlide;

skills.push_back(frontFloat);
skills.push_back(frontGlide);

skills[0]["Wetface"]='C';
skills[0]["relaxed"]='C';
skills[0]["comfortable"]='I';

for (auto& x : skills) {
   for (auto& skillPair : x){
      cout<< skillPair.first << " => " << skillPair.second << '\n';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
skills.push_back(frontFloat);
skills.push_back(frontGlide); //this will actually be stored as value not as reference. so the vector will contain only values from map at the pushing into the vector. But in your case you can push that as reference.
```

Below code slight modification of your code with pointer reference.

```
vector<map<string, char>*> skills; //here I'm storing the address of the map not the value.
map<string, char> frontFloat;
map<string, char> frontGlide;

skills.push_back(&frontFloat); //here i'm pushing the address to the vector.
skills.push_back(&frontGlide);

frontFloat["Wetface"]='C';
frontFloat["relaxed"]='C';
frontFloat["comfortable"]='I';

// ...

for (auto x : skills) {
   for (auto it=(*x).begin(); it!=(*x).end(); ++it){ //(*x) dereferencing the map address to the value.
      cout<< it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';
   }
}
return 0;
}
```

This will work as per your need. And whenever you iterate over the vector you will get only the current values of the map. I hope this will help you.